# Shortcut/Widget to set a reminder in Google Now

Tags: app-widgets, home-screen-shortcuts, google-now, google-search

I use Google Now to set reminders quite often. At times when I'd rather not be talking at my phone to add a reminder, I wish I could have a button on my homescreen that would take me straight to the Add Reminder card.

I just found out about the "Set Reminder" option in Google Now's quick settings panel. It's much quicker than typing out "add reminder" in the search bar. But still, having a shortcut to that "add reminder card", or a widget which would add reminders from the homescreen would be pretty advantageous (I would probably prefer a shortcut).

I've tried using a few of the Google Search app's activities, but none seem to take my straight to the add reminder card.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any way to view Google Now reminders on desktop via browser?

Comment: Not that I know of, but that might be a question for a different stack exchange site.

Comment: @Ze'ev I just googled "add reminder" and it looks like they've added that functionality! Woot :)))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to add a shortcut to the "add reminder" card at the moment. I've had a look through the Activities as well and none of them appear to do what you want.

There is a "Set reminder" option in the menu within Google Now which may help? Click the three dots at the bottom right (you might need to scroll down) and you should see the "Set reminder" option.

Comment: I did notice the "Set Reminder" option in the menu, which certainly helps.

Answer (score 4):

There is the activity

`Google Search > com.google.android.voicesearch.fragments.reminders.EditReminderActivity`

which does exactly what you want.

Comment: How exactly do we use this?

Comment: In my case, I'm using the purity ROM which allows me to define shortcuts on the sides of the Google Now shortcut, and there I have two "activity"to chose: a standard one and the one from Nova. I found that activity in the standard one. In other case I could just add this activity to the desktop. Try this: add a shortcut to the desktop and chose "activity", then search for this activity I mention in my reply.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if you found an answer or not but here is what I did. It requires [Desktop VisualizeR](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.bii.android.app.dskvzr).

Open Chrome on your mobile device and search for "Google Now Add Reminder". This will initiate a reminder card through through Chrome. In Chrome Menu  select "Share..." Then select "DVR save to clipboard". Then create the shortcut on your home screen using the Desktop Visualizer app.

Found an easier way...lol...Bookmark it and add a shortcut to your home screen.

Comment: That's a clever idea, I'll have to try it out!

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 options which I have found.

1. If you use Inbox by Google it comes with an add reminder shortcut available in widgets. (This opens up in the Inbox app, and the dialog to create a reminder is not as friendly as Google Now, especially if you want to add a custom time.)
2. Supposedly Google Now will ask you if you would like to add a shortcut to the home screen after you use it to create a reminder, but I can't get it to ask me.
3. [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en)  - This is what I use, directions below.

---

## Unders Tasks

1. Add Task (+) New Task
2. Add Action (+) System -> Send Intent

---

#### Under Send Intent

```
Action:     com.google.android.goolequicksearchbox.GOOGLE_SEARCH
Cat:        Default
Mime Type:  (leave blank)
Data:       (leave blank)
Extra:      type:String
Extra:      query:add reminder
```

You can then add to your Home Screen using the Tasker Widget

Comment: Nice! At last found someone who gave a direct access to the actual reminders on the device.

Answer (score 2):

Note 5 - Nova Launcher - Android v6.0.1 (and yes, i am still waiting for the update in AUSTRALIA)

1. find the Google Calender app on your phone (mine is in the drawer)
2. Press/hold the icon to launch the alt menu to add appointment or reminder
3. Press/Hold the reminder menu and put it on your desktop

Answer (score 1):

After reading a while here, you can do the following.

Google on your mobile `Google Now Add Reminder` and add it to your bookmarks.

Then add the Bookmark widget to your desktop on your mobile, pointing to that bookmark and voilá!

Comment: This still works in 2021, well after Google Now and Inbox have ceased to exist.

Answer (score 1):

This method should work:

- Locate Google Calendar Icon and long press it:
- Press on the 4 dots on the right of the "New reminder" and drag it to the home screen, it will become a shortcut:
- Pressing this shortcut will take you directly to creating a New Google Reminder:

My Blog Post with Snapshots about it:

[How to add a Shortcut on Android Home Screen to create a New Google Reminder](http://naumankhan.blogspot.com/2017/08/how-to-add-shortcut-on-android-home.html)